Concave-convexlike minimax theorem
In "On general minimax theorems" (M. Sion), the following result is used:

Let $M$ and $N$ be any spaces, $f$ a function on $M \times N$ that is concave-convexlike$^1$. Suppose that for any $c < \inf_N \sup_M f$ there exists a finite subset $X \subset M$ such that for any $\nu \in N$ there is an $x \in X$ with $f(x, \nu) > c$.  Then $\sup_M \inf_N f = \inf_N \sup_M f$.

They claim that this is "an immediate consequence of von Neumann's minimax theorem".  Why is that the case?

$^1$: A function $f : M \times N$ is defined to be "concavelike in $M$" if for every $\mu_1, \mu_2 \in M$ and $t \in [0, 1]$, there exists $\mu \in M$ such that
$$tf(\mu_1, \nu) + (1 - t)f(\mu_2, \nu) \le f(\mu, \nu) \quad\quad\text{for all $\nu \in N$}$$
and "concave-convexlike" means concavelike in $M$ and convexlike in $N$.
